# Session Timing out while working

Tags: angularjs, ajax, spring, session

Some background about my application:
I am working on an application which has Angular JS and Spring MVC. This application is deployed on Weblogic. The session timeout value is set as 30 minute in the web.xml.

Problem Statement:
As soon as the user logs in into the application and starts working, the AngularJS starts making the AJAX calls. Even though the user is working on the application but still after almost 30 minutes the application session times out. After timeout the subsequent AJAX call(s) returns the  status code 302.

My question is that how do I handle this scenario. Because the user is continuously working on the screens and still the application is timing out.

Comment: Are you seeing the session cookie value being passed with the AJAX calls? If the AJAX calls don't send the session id then the session will timeout.

Comment: Hey Brian..Thanks for  the reply..Every time the session id is being sent over in the AJAX calls